# Convert persian input to gregorian in Blade Laravel

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Hi I am not good at JavaScript and have problem. I hope anyone can help me.
I want to get date from one input and change it to georgian and put it in another input.
And mix some code but didn't work:

```
<input type="date" id="one" oninput="myFunction()">
<input  id="two">

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var src = document.getElementById("one"),
        dst = document.getElementById("two");
        let text = src.toLocaleDateString('en-Us');
    src.addEventListener('input', function() {
        dst.value = text.value;
    });
};
</script>
```

thanks anyway